# Click event not happening in Python with Selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Friends facing challenges again in following scenarios using Python with Selenium web driver:-

1. Click event not happening on clicking the link name as "Area Rank Web".
   HTML Code for MSTR Report is as follows:-

   ```
   <td class="mstrLargeIconViewItemText" rowspan="1" colspan="1" cx="[2,1,0,5,1,6,7]" cxid="folderAllModes_cmm" oid="600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0" oty="55"><a title="Run Document" class="mstrLargeIconViewItemLink" onclick="return submitLink(this, event);" href="Main.aspx?evt=2048001&amp;src=Main.aspx.2048001&amp;visMode=0&amp;currentViewMedia=1&amp;documentID=600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0" runasexpress="1" alt="Run Document"></a><div class="mstrLargeIconViewItemName"><span sty="nm"><a title="Area Rank Web" class="mstrLink" onclick="return submitLink(this, event);" href="Main.aspx?evt=2048001&amp;src=Main.aspx.2048001&amp;visMode=0&amp;currentViewMedia=1&amp;documentID=600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0" runasexpress="1">Area Rank Web</a></span></div><div class="mstrLargeIconViewItemOwner"><label>Owner:</label><span><div title="Administrator" class="owner">Administrator</div></span></div><div class="mstrLargeIconViewItemModified"><label>Modified:</label><span><div timestamp="1525148536000">5/1/18 4:22:16 AM</div></span></div><div class="mstrLargeIconViewItemDescription"></div><div></div><div class="mstrLargeIconViewItemActions"><span><a class="mstrLink" onclick="if (!mstrFolderActions.checkACL(this, event, '600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0', 55)) return; return submitLink(this, event);" href="Main.aspx?evt=3032&amp;src=Main.aspx.3032&amp;objectType_3032=55&amp;objectID_3032=600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0" ty="sub">Subscriptions</a></span></div></td>
   ```

   I tried following ways but not getting success:

   ```
   #driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[title='Area Rank Web']").click();
   #driver.find_elements_by_class_name (("mstrLargeIconViewItemName") and contains(.,'Area Rank Web')).click()
   #driver.find_element_by_id("600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0").click()
   #driver.find_element_by_css_selector("600E4BA841AC84797221F7BB5262C3E0").click()
   #WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mstrLargeIconViewItemText']/span[@class='mstrIcon-lg' and contains(.,'Area Rank Web')]"))).click()
   ```

   2.
   There is a block having two values as:- AREA, DISTRICT. You can select more than value and then click on arrow button which moves selected content to the right side of block and then click on submit button

   HTML code:

   ```
   <div title="AREA" class="mstrListBlockItemSelected" style="margin-top: 0px;"><div class="mstrBGIcon_ae mstrListBlockItemName" style="background-position: 2px 50%; padding-left: 23px;">DSI</div></div>

   <div title="DISTRICT" class="mstrListBlockItem" style="margin-top: 0px;"><div class="mstrBGIcon_ae mstrListBlockItemName" style="background-position: 2px 50%; padding-left: 23px;">ONC</div></div>
   ```

Tried following ways but click event is not happening

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: You can ignore second issue. In first m trying to click on an object not sure whether it is link or not. I have attached HTML code for your reference. M trying to generate click event on that link but it is not happening. I tried probable possible ways which i shared but not getting success. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try link_text/ partial_link_text instead?

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Area Rank Web').click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Area Rank Web').click()
```

Also, try having an explicit wait before you click on the link.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(
             (By.LINK_TEXT, 'Area Rank Web')
))
```

if all the above fails, use `execute_script` method to invoke a click event on the link

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Area Rank Web')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', link)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing details. For first two scripts received following error message:-ElementClickInterceptedException: Element not clickable at point (411,73). Other element would receive the click:. Where as the last script worked out.

Comment: `ElementClickInterceptedException` Indicates that a click could not be properly executed because the target element was obscured in some way. Check if some other element on your page is on top of(partially or fully) the target element